# Could human skin be home to chromataphores, like a chamelion's or an octopus's

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, science-fiction

Could human skin be home to chromataphores, like a chamelion's?   I'm assuming a technology advanced enough to create designer organisms, including designer humans. In other words, tech that will be invented many long years from now.

I was thinking about writing a story that features such color changing humans, but I don't know anything about the physiological trade-offs involved. And that's why I posted this question.